# Display left and right aligned content with variable width line between

Tags: css, mobile

I'm looking for an alternate mobile presentation of data that is displayed as a table in its desktop form.  I saw a good example that looked like this:

```
account____________________ 1234567
due date_______________ 10-NOV-2016
balance_____________________$100.00
note_____description and stuff here
```

The example I found looks better than this.  But the idea is that what would have been the column header is left aligned and what would have been the column data is right aligned and a horizontal rule of variable width joins the two.  If there are additional rows of data the same presentation would be repeated for each row, though in my context only a few would ever be present.

Unfortunately, I observed this within a mobile application which, though based in HTML, cannot be viewed as HTML.  I don't know how this presentation was accomplished, and have not been able to formulate search criteria that has produced anything applicable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use positions here, [see this pen](https://codepen.io/nexgendevs/pen/ZBawPV) for more info.

```
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
li {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 9;
}
li span {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  bottom: -1px;
  z-index: 10;
}
li span.label {
  left: 0;
}
li span.value {
  right: 0
}
```

Comment: Hello @KeithLosset, Kindly mark this answer correct then. I am glad that I have helped someone...

Answer (score 0):

flex & a list might do

```css
li,
li b {
  display: flex;
}

li b,
li b:after {
  flex: 1;
}

li b:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: dotted;
  margin: 0.7em 0.5em auto;
}



/* demo makeup*/
ul {
  padding: 1em;
  background: gray;
  background-clip: content-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}
li:nth-child(even){
  background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2),transparent,rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><b>Account</b> 123</li>
  <li><b>Accounts</b> 123 456</li>
  <li><b>Account Account</b> 123<br/> 456 789</li>
  <li><b>Account Act</b> 123 456 789 000</li>
  <li><b>Act</b> 123 456</li>
  <li><b>count</b> 123 456 000</li>
  </ul>
```